# Reusing DNS in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

Is there a way to just point our DNS to an existing Azure App Services IP? Right now our site is using `.azurewebsites.net` but we don't want that and want to use our own domain name. Is there a way to do this? As much as possible we dont want to make name server changes or anything. Is there a way to point our DNS to the IP of our App Service?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-your-domain? Anything that is unclear or that doesn't work for you?

Comment: juunas's comment is right, you can follow the document to configure it to use your custom domain.

Comment: If your custom domain is not purchased on azure, such as godaddy, then you need to perform similar operations in godaddy's management configuration center.

Comment: @MadzQuestioning Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as juunas pointed out in the comment, you can follow the [map custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-your-domain) document to configure a custom domain for azure service.

You can use Azure DNS to configure a custom DNS name for Azure App Service.

[image]

Type the fully qualified domain name that you added a CNAME record for.

[image]